# Open source alternative to Docusign?

Tags: open-source, pdf, email, contract-manager

When I Google "Alternative to Docisign" then lots pop up, but none of them are open source.

If I Google "open source legal contract" then https://accordproject.org/ pops up, but I can't really figure out if it is a DokuSign alternative.

Does anyone know of such that is open source?

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Especially missing: what features do you need? What OS should it run on?

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of system, you also have to consider all the operational issues associated with it e.g. verification of person signing, document management, trust, etc. So please explain more about the context within which it would be used, as it may require a combination of many tools.

But the ones I have come across include:

- https://docassemble.org/
- https://libresign.github.io/

I have not used them myself.

Also, these days there are also blockchain-related tools/solutions.

Answer (score 0):

We are currently building one here, called Documenso: https://github.com/documenso/documenso

Comment: Can you give some details about the proposed program and how it fulfils the question?

Comment: If you are looking for a ready to use Document Signing solution, that is completely open source (UI to signing) as far as I know there is none. That's why I started Documenso, so we can build one.

Comment: Accord Project does not seem to have anything resembling this, if that was also your question. The code they have is mostly open source, but not what you are looking for.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/65758)